# What's is @content used for in Sass?

Tags: css, sass

I'm learning SCSS, and I stumbled upon `@content`. I really don't understand what its use is, since up until now I'm able to get the same output without it. Example:

```
@mixin context--alternate-template {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  @content
}

.content-sample {
  @include context--alternate-template {
    .important-thing {
      color: red;
    }
    &.is-italic {
      font-family: 'my-webfont-italic';
    }
  }

  // outside mixin call
  background-color: black;
}
```

gets the same output as

```
@mixin context--alternate-template {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.content-sample {
    
    @include context--alternate-template;
  
    .important-thing {
      color: red;
    }
    &.is-italic {
      font-family: 'my-webfont-italic';
    }

  // outside mixin call
  background-color: black;
}
```

Can someone give me a good example where `@content` is actually useful (so there is no other way to get the same output without `@content`, or without making the code a lot more complex without it)?

Answer (score 1):

`@content` keyword is meant to include content, passed from the place of invocation, therefore you can customise your `@mixin` by including context-sensitive `scss` code.

```
@mixin apply-to-ie6-only {
  * html {
    @content
  }
}

@include apply-to-ie6-only {
  #logo {
    background-image: url(/logo.gif);
  }
}
```

Take a look at this example:
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/sasss-content-directive

Comment: Does it mean that the main usefulness of @content is the possibility to create empty rules, so I can avoid writing many times various nested selectors?

Comment: @FabioCosta usually you will need `@content` when you want to make your mixins more flexible, by allowing external content insertion

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly useful in conjunction with `@media queries` or other "generated* rules.

E.g.

```
$breakpoints: (
  "mobile-s": 320px,
  "mobile-m": 475px,
);

@mixin forBreakpoint($breakpoint) {
  @for $i from 1 through length($breakpoints) {
    @if nth(nth($breakpoints, $i), 1) == $breakpoint {
      @media (min-width: #{nth(nth($breakpoints, $i), 2)}) {
        @content;
      }
    }
  }
}

.foo {
  @include forBreakpoint(mobile-s) {
    foo: foo;
  }
}

.bar {
  @include forBreakpoint(mobile-m) {
    bar: bar;
  }
}
```

Will output:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .foo {
    foo: foo;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 475px) {
  .bar {
    bar: bar;
  }
}
```